# How do you get rid of next-prv done buttons on top of iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, mobile-website

I'm working on a mobile web and in a I just want to get the iPhone basic keyboard without Next Prev Done buttons. Anybody knows how?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can change the type of keyboard though: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, **you cannot** get rid of those buttons for Mobile Web.

Comment: I did some research and realized that.